# How do I check if server really has RAID 10 enabled?

Tags: linux, raid, centos6, raid10

I have a dedicated server with 4 hdd and RAID 10, with Cent OS 6.4

How can I check if RAID is really enabled. I'm in doubt because on another server with RAID 10 enabled, I can see in /dev sg0 sg1 sg2 sg3 sg4, and with the command smartctl -d scsi --all /dev/sga1 for example, I can get info about the disks.

In this new server, I don't have this.

Is there any other way to check if it really have RAID enabled?

Comment: Why don't you ask the hosting company? What makes you doubt that you have R10?

Comment: If this is a hardware RAID, there should be some cli utitity to check your RAID configuration. What RAID controller do you have? When in doubt, `lspci` should tell you more about it.

Comment: Pull two disks? :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to determine your RAID controller.  This could be any number of hardware RAID cards or software RAID.

Once the RAID controller is identified, you can then download and install the appropriate RAID utilities to check RAID status.

I have found many hosting providers do not actually monitor RAID status.  So it is good to check yourself and configure alerts if possible.

Either ask the company what RAID controller is in use or you can use a tool like `lspci` or `lshw` (available in the EPEL) to list hardware.

I often use `lshw` to confirm the hardware I've ordered form a IaaS provider is indeed what it is supposed to be.

`lshw` man page:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw

Comment: smartctl -d scsi --all /dev/sg0 returns this:

Vendor:               LSI
Product:              MR9260-4i
Revision:             2.13
User Capacity:        598.879.502.336 bytes [598 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x600605b0068d4c8019ea2e4109137d6a
Serial number:        006a7d1309412eea19804c8d06b00506
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Fri Oct 11 09:34:47 2013 MDT
Device does not support SMART

Comment: So. It looks like the controller is: MegaRAID SAS
9260-4i

Comment: And that means without special tools the OS just sees the resulting raid as new, one had disc. Get the tools, then you can look into the controller.